# failed to send WATCHDOG=1

Tags: system-installation, 17.10, systemd-journald

I have just installed Ubuntu (v 17.10) for the first time and was suggested to reboot the system. portable Acer Inspire R3-131

Ubuntu cannot reboot:

```
[ 9934.778997] systemd-journald[955]: failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

I'm not a specialist HELP

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: I want anything BUT rebooting

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug, reproducable also in VM.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1754328

If there will be a fix, they have to:
1. Either release a new DVD ISO
2. Apply the updates during the installation

Comment: How do I get rid of it without rebooting?

Answer (score 1):

Update ubuntu properly. Write following commands in **terminal**:

```
sudo apt-get update
update-manager
```

After completion update, Write following command in **terminal**:

```
reboot
```

Hopefully, Problem will be solved.
If the problem is still exits:

- Press and Hold Power button and let the PC to turn off forcibly.
- Turn on PC now, it will on perfectly.
- if it throws fsck error, write command:
   `fsck -yf /dev/sdaX` 
  **Done**

Comment: Dear all thanks for your help and comments, Just to inform I finally fixed the pb by not on ly redirecting on the line   shimx64.efi. for booting but also saying to the bios to beging with this line (which I missed intially) Anyway i'm happy now. Thanks again !!!